# Can I default a function argument to the value of __FILE__ at the caller?

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor, optional-arguments

In C++, can I have a defaulted argument to a function which defaults to `__PRETTY_FUNCTION___`, `___FILE___`, and `___LINE__` as defined at the point of the caller and not the point the defaults are supplied in a header file without using macros?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't, but you can acheive this behavior with an additional macro. For instance:

```
#DEFINE THROW(e) throwException(e, __FILE__, __LINE__);
```

On a side note, `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` is not standard.

Answer (score 1):

No. Macros are expanded at the source line where they occur.

Answer (score 0):

You probably can... but definitely not with the restriction you mentioned (no macros).