# C++ - style passing caller file and line to function (equivalent of __FILE__ and __LINE__)

Tags: c++, macros, compiler-construction

I know, that my question is similar to this:
[Passing the caller __FILE__ __LINE__ to a function without using macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4196431/passing-the-caller-file-line-to-a-function-without-using-macro)

But I'm wondering, why there is no c++ equivalent of caller file and line passing to a function.

Having classes, templates, default arguments and more strict const-correctness makes a lot of macro usage obsolete, but when I want to pass caller file and line to a function, I will go in trouble for 2 reasons: 1. Default arguments (hard to replace all kinds of calls with a macro), 2. Macros break class member name scope. (startTimer macro would be global)

Thinking about the default arguments to functions, why are there no default-args-style replacements for **FILE** and **LINE** macros? It could be done like this:

```
void startTimer(int type, int id=0, string file = _CALLER_::FILE, int line = _CALLER_::LINE)
```

If the compiler, while looking for function calls of startTimer, can replace the id parameter with 0, where it isn't mentioned, it should be possible to replace file and line with the corresponding *CALLER* members, which in this example depend on the file, being processed, and the line where the call is made - something that the compiler knows while parsing a cpp file.

Knowing the caller of a member function may be useful for debugging - on which file/line has something been called, which leads to a problem later.

Comment: `__FILE__` is not a macro. And there's no way to answer this question. The only answer to "why doesn't C++ have X feature" is "because you haven't proposed it to the working group yet".

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit: 1. ISO C++ 2012 draft, 16.8 Predefined macro names: "The following **macro** names shall be defined by the implementation: [...] _ _ FILE _ _ [...]" 2. Often there is a reason why something hasn't been suggested or accepted yet, which would be interesting to know.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I default a function argument to the value of \_\_FILE\_\_ at the caller?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3462789/can-i-default-a-function-argument-to-the-value-of-file-at-the-caller)

Comment: Your question may be inspired by the recent caller information feature in .NET, cf. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh534540.aspx. Its implementation in C# (CLR?) is based on attributes. A similar functionality in the C/C++ world could perhaps be achieved by using pragmas. But the semantics of pragmas are, afaics, not specified by the standard beyond the statement that their effect is implementation-defined. In other words their purpose is specifically to communicate with specific implementations, not to to add standard language features.

Comment: @PeterSchneider: Whoops, I was thinking of `__function__`, of course. The rest of my comment stands. BTW you should cite _standards_, not drafts.

Comment: @PeterSchneider Standard C++ supports attributes since C++11 (the attributes themselves are mostly implementation-defined, like pragmas).

Comment: @Nuclear, please do take the time to communicate this request to the C++ standard committee. This sounds like a relatively minor modification of the language (compared to, say, the ability to look at the stack above you). With proper lobbying and proposal massaging - maybe it can make it in to the language? You'd be doing us all a great service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think to have the feature *optional*, i.e. have it part of the function declaration the way you suggest, is not easy or not possible. The compiler must insert the needed information at, well, compile time (because file and line information are lost at run time), but at that time it may not know at all which function will be called in the case of virtual member functions or even plain old function pointers which get assigned in unpredictable ways.

But it would perhaps be possible to have *all* functions receive two hidden and undeclared parameters, the same way that member functions receive a hidden this pointer. In that scenario the compiler doesn't need to know which function is called because *all* functions receive the hidden caller line and file parameters.

Even if that is possible, I see the following problems:

1. That's obviously a major change to
   an implementation, and probably to the language. (I'm not sure
   whether it could be done behind the scenes by an implementation
   which still claims to comply with today's standard.) It would be
   impossible in C for all practical purposes because it would break
   existing ABIs (unless Microsoft does it ;-) ). That would be less of an
   issue in C++ where ABI compatibility is much worse anyway.
2. It may be a performance problem that two parameters need to be passed to each function although they aren't often needed at all, and it may perhaps even be a memory problem on tiny (e.g. embedded) systems because the stack would grow faster. (Of course you could claim that they shouldn't build up such a deep stack to begin with, but still.)

If you consider that the functionality is available right now in the shape of a macro (with the only downside of name space pollution which is totally manageable), the benefit/effort ratio simply isn't good enough, is my guess.